# Bug in handling backslashed Cyrillic symbols in v.10.0.0?

Tags: front-end, bugs, character-encoding

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.1**

**UPDATE: Now both the inputs `"\б"` and `"\\б"` are interpreted as `"\\б"` and displayed in `OutputForm` as `"\б"`, `InputForm["\б"]` returns `"\\б"` and `StringLength["\\б"]` returns `2`**.

---

Consider:

```
"\бвгд" // FullForm
"\\бвгд" // FullForm
```

In v.8.0.4 I get this:

> ```
> "\\:0431\:0432\:0433\:0434"
> "\\\:0431\:0432\:0433\:0434"
> ```

But v.10.0.0 adds redundant backslash before the first backslashed Cyrillic symbol:

> ```
> "\\\:0431\:0432\:0433\:0434"
> "\\\\:0431\:0432\:0433\:0434"
> ```

[image: screenshot]

As the result it is not possible to open any file which name (or name of a directory in the path) starts from a Cyrillic symbol.

Also after evaluating the above (in the case the Cyrillic symbols were typed, not pasted in the Notebook) the following bugs appear:

- When I try to cut by pressing `Ctrl+X` any `Cell` or group of cells in this Notebook I get http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ opened in my browser and nothing changed in the FrontEnd
- After some additional editing (entering backslashed Cyrillic symbols after the quote `"` but without entering the closing quote and without evaluation of the cell)  an attempt to cut an input cell by pressing `Ctrl+X` results in commenting all the code in the selected input cell. Pressing `Ctrl+X` again uncomments the code.

All the above manipulations with `Ctrl+X` give this result when English keyboard locale is selected.

Does anyone also observe this? Is there a workaround?

P.S. OS Win7 x64.

Comment: I think this may have to do with the change to a single system font. In previous versions, '\б` or other Cyrillic character would not replace \ with \\, whereas this would happen with Latin characters (as long as they weren't escape sequences). This was true in v9 as well, but in v10 letters from both alphabets behave the same. Does the single slash not work for you? On Win 8.1 x64 (v10) this works fine for me: `Import["алексей\попков","Text"]` > `привет!`

Comment: One workaround for `Import` is to use `FileNameJoin`.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I don't think `"\\:0431\:0432\:0433\:0434"` is properly formed -- that is, I think the bug is in V8.0.4 (and V9.0.1, too). If I paste the string in V8.0.4 and execute it, the output displays as nine characters, `\:0431вгд`, which seems the proper interpretation (compare with `StringLength["\бвгд"]`).  A similar thing happens with other unicode characters.  That it used to work suggests offsetting bugs or intentional flexibility in processing resource-locator strings.  Similarly, the V10 string `"\\\\:0431\:0432\:0433\:0434"` seems to be missing a backslash.

Comment: @Michael It sounds like we have bugs both in versions 8,9 and in v.10 but now the things become worse: filename handling is broken.

Comment: I usually use `FileNameJoin` anyway, or do you mean it's not working?  (Btw, I don't have Windows, so I can only check the filename string in *Mma*; I can't check whether the file can be opened with the string.)

Comment: @Michael It works, check my answer.

Comment: [Possibly related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55086/12)

Comment: I have the same problem with broken shortcuts.

Comment: In 10.0.1 I get three slashes in both cases.

Comment: Has this been fixed now?  We should mark it appropriately if possible.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, in version 10.1.0 the described bugs are fixed. I'm not sure in which version they were finally fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For file operations two workarounds currently work:

1) Use slash `/` instead of double backslash in the paths to files under Windows:

```
Import["D:/test/кириллическое название/файл.txt"]
```

2) Use `FileNameJoin` or `StringJoin`:

```
Import[FileNameJoin[{"D:", "test", "кириллическое название", "файл.txt"}]]

Import[StringJoin[{"D:", "\\", "test", "\\", "кириллическое название", "\\", "файл.txt"}]]
```

Note that both produce just ordinary double-backslashed output:

```
FileNameJoin[{"D:", "test", "кириллическое название", "файл.txt"}]
```

> ```
> "D:\\test\\кириллическое название\\файл.txt"
> ```

Manipulations inside of the Kernel are safe:

```
path = File /. FileInformation["D:/test/кириллическое название/файл.txt"]
Import[path]
```

> "D:\test\кириллическое название\файл.txt"

(`Import` works as expected).

But copying this and pasting into the FrontEnd gives a string that is parsed incorrectly:

```
Import["D:\\test\\кириллическое название\\файл.txt"]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[12]:= Import::nffil: File not found during Import. >>
>
> $Failed
> ```

So it is clear that this is a FrontEnd bug.