# Cannot import Excel (xls or xlsx) files which have non-ASCII characters in the name

Tags: bugs, import, excel

It seems mma9 works fine, but with mma10 it fail to load a file name with Chinese characters.  I use MacBook Pro(Retina) with OSX 10.10.2, and *Mathematica* 10.0.0.0.  I need the file name with Chinese characters, and how can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
In[309]:= Import["20150226-9999指數.xls", {"Data", -1}]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[309]:= Import::fnfnd: File /Users/TWSE-data/20150226-9999指數.xls not found. >>
>
> Out[309]= $Failed
> ```

---

Let me clear situation now:

.txt file format works fine, but not for .xls file with Chinese character
It may be system dependent problem.

```
In[37]:= Import["4拷貝.txt"]

Out[37]= "this is test file"

In[38]:= Import["20150226-9999TWRI拷貝.xls"]

During evaluation of In[38]:= Import::fnfnd: File /Users/TWSE-data/20150226-9999TWRI拷貝.xls not found. >>

Out[38]= $Failed

In[39]:= Import["20150226-9999TWRI.xls"]

Out[39]= {{{92.48, 92.48, 92.48, 92.48, 0., 0.}, {92.48, 92.48, 92.48,
    92.48, 0., 0.}}}

In[40]:= $Version

Out[40]= "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"
```

Comment: Upgrade to Mathematica 10.0.2.

Comment: Yes, it seeems that, i check all the path and file name, only mma10.0.0.0 will cause the issue.

Comment: path seems can work, but file name with Chinese character seems not work still with mma10.0.2

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/80l5qpizcsejzsr/Screenshot%202015-03-09%2023.48.46.png?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you for trying, I can open file with .txt format, but still can't open .xls file name with Chinese character. Please see re-edit question. My issue is the "file name", not "path" with Chinese characters.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem now.  It happens with *any* non-ASCII character, and it seems to be specific to XLS or XLSX files.

Comment: You should report this problem to [Wolfram Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/), so it can be fixed.  It looks like a bug.

Comment: Dedicated thread: "[How to workaround failures with Unicode filepaths?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143953/280)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce this problem on OS X with Mathematica 10.0.2, but with XLS and XLSX files *only*.  Thus it's different from [this bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55086/12) which existed in version 10.0.0 and affected *all* files, and was fixed later.

I believe that this is a bug and you should report this to Wolfram Support so it can be fixed.  Mathematica.SE is not a website run by Wolfram Research and reporting bugs only here won't get them fixed.

---

Here's a workaround that doesn't require renaming the file:

```
In[1]:= Import["~/Desktop/中.xlsx", "XLSX"]

During evaluation of In[1]:= Import::fnfnd: File /Users/szhorvat/Desktop/中.xlsx not found. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as XLSX format. >>

Out[1]= $Failed

In[2]:= stream = OpenRead["~/Desktop/中.xlsx"]
Out[2]= InputStream["/Users/szhorvat/Desktop/中.xlsx", 3]

In[3]:= Import[stream, "XLSX"]
Out[3]= {{{1.}, {2.}, {3.}}}

In[4]:= Close[stream]
Out[4]= "/Users/szhorvat/Desktop/中.xlsx"
```

You could package this up into a function for convenience.