# 11.3 - import of files with paths containing non-ASCII characters

Tags: bugs, import, version-11.3, backslide

`Import`: Version 11.2 works correctly, no problem with non-ASCII characters in the path of file. But upgrated version 11.3

a) does not import these files

b) reports an error `Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as XLSX format` (i.e. unclear problem report, no "non--ASCII characters" or some similar)

How to fix this problem, with respect to previous functionality?

EDIT: This is for 11.3 while [the previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76871/cannot-import-excel-xls-or-xlsx-files-which-have-non-ascii-characters-in-the-n) was wrt an unrelated issue in 10.0

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143953/12

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because it may be considered a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) and therefore  [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD). Please [edit] your question if you consider this is a mistake and give great emphasis in what was NOT answered in the other question. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed.

Comment: Brilliant general solutions in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143953/how-to-workaround-failures-with-unicode-filepaths I know that I searched for solutions in March but I missed this one. I think it has to do with that it worked in 11.2 and then stopped working in 11.3. Importing from files is an important use case - should be developed and tested with higher attention at WRI.

Comment: @rhermans To be fair, these posts had two completely different answers. The previous post was solved by upgrading to 10.0.2, and was a different Unicode xls/xlsx bug. This is a new incantation of a similar bug but, and DataLegacy was only introduced in 11.3, the version this question was asking about and received new information for. I realize this probably wasn't immediately obvious without knowing about the implementation update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The defect is known since March 2018. According to the support, it will be addressed in future versions (perhaps the next one - my guess).

If you want to use the legacy converter:

```
Import["fö.xlsx", {"DataLegacy"}]
```

or

```
Import["fö.xlsx", {"SheetsLegacy"}]
```

For me, the new import functionality seemed to be better so I changed the paths & filenames instead

Comment: Seems like this is fixed in v12. Tested with exporting and importing a file with "ö" in its name