# Annoying FrontEnd bugs in Mathematica 10

Tags: front-end, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Recently I installed *Mathematica 10* on *Windows 8 x64* machine. Before that I had a prerelease version of *Mathematica 10* installed on my laptop. I observed very annoying bugs in the FrontEnd on both machines: at some random moment during editing a notebook, some keybord shortcuts (e.g. `Ctrl+Z`, `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+S` etc) start doing things completely different from they are supposed to do: change the notebook stylesheet, open new windows, comment out the selected text etc. The menu items corresponding to those shortcuts do the same crazy things. To save the current notebook I have to invoke `NotebookSave[]` function because there is no way do it using graphical interface. Restarting *Mathematica* solves the problem for a while, but soon it reappears. Does anybody else observe this behavior?

---

*Update:* It looks like this bug was fixed in version 10.0.2. Many thanks to the developers!

Comment: To Save your notebook you can use SaveAs - it works. But the M10 is evidently not ready for release...

Comment: A similar bug: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54804/7288

Comment: I am adding the bugs tag because the existing answer indicates that this is not a localized problem somehow produced by a unique software conflict, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have observed this exact behavior in 10.0.0, and just now in 10.0.1.0 (where I hoped it'd be fixed). For example, when I press CTRL+X to cut, I get this:

[image: Pressing CTRL + x]

If I just close the notebook, the bug persists. Closing the app entirely seems take care of it for a little while, and then it comes back for me, too. Not fun at all. :(

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that, unfortunately the bug also appears in 10.0.1

Answer (score 6):

I use Mathematica 10 on two machines (Win 8 x64 and Win 7 x64) and this bug is present on both ones. As far as I can see, FrontEnd goes crazy when user changes keyboard language from English to some other (Russian in my case). From that moment, some keyboard shortcuts and corresponding functions work as intended only in Russian keyboard layout; shortcuts typed from English keyboard spawn new windows, open web pages and so on. As Eight Hour Lunch mentioned, only restarting the whole program helps.

Comment: This happens to me too (Win 8.1 x64, Mma 10.0.1.0). I think I've always switched keyboards so far. I'll try now not to.