# The "Save" under "File" and "Undo" under "Edit" do not work in Mathematica 10.0

Tags: front-end, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Each time I click "Save" or "Undo" button from the notebook menu, some new notebook window similar to this pops up:
[image]

And the file is not actually saved or the last step is not actually "undone".
Is it a bug?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should post a video or a gif of the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that this issue is too peculiar, I'd better just reinstall it or wait for upgrading.

Comment: Upgrade from 10.0.0 to 10.0.1, problem solved.

Comment: Problem occurred again the next day! A different window pops up.

Comment: I can explain what's going on. v10 before 10.0.2 conflict with Chinese IME (such as Sougou), you may find that there is a blink when you switch IME.(This doesn't happen in v9 or earlier version) I've reported this to WR, and problem is solved in v10.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, this bug has been fixed as of version 10.0.2.

See also these other questions: [(58799)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58799), [(86891)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86891), [(72750)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72750) and [(90054)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90054).