# Ctrl-V doesn't paste, it opens Find and Replace dialog instead

Tags: windows, keyboard

I just installed *Mathematica* 10 on Windows 7 today. Everything works fine, except the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> doesn't paste, it opens the "Find and Replace" dialog. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, it also opens the "Find and Replace" dialog.

To make things clear, the wired thing is:

```
Ctrl-V -> "Find and Replace"
Ctrl-F -> "Find and Replace"
```

Do I need to set anything in order to let <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> behave normally? Or how to fix it?

Comment: Is this a bad installation? I've used version 10 on Windows before, and was able to copy and paste as I always have.

Comment: Do you switch between different keyboards layouts? I think this is a known issue (see e.g. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58799/169)) and unfortunately seems to persist even in 10.0.2, but if one knows the source one can at least try to avoid these changes...

Comment: Just a now about the comment above: I was confused and did make the test with the wrong version (10.0.1). I just tried the correct version (10.0.2) and there could not reproduce the problem, so there is no evidence that it still exists in 10.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the instances I have heard of this issue was pre 10.0.2.  If you haven't already, you should update.

If this is happening in 10.0.2, you should contact tech support.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this but probably you can change those keyboard shortcuts just editing the MenuSetup.tr. Copy the file:

`$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh/MenuSetup.tr`

and put it into:

`$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh/`

There you can search the Paste and Find lines, and exchange their MenuKey:

```
MenuItem["Paste", FrontEnd`Paste[Automatic], MenuKey["v", Modifiers->{"Command"}]]

MenuItem["Find...", KernelExecute[If[CurrentValue["PluginEnabled"], FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "FindExpression"], FrontEnd`DialogOpen["Find.nb", True]]], MenuEvaluator -> "System", MenuKey["f", Modifiers->{"Command"}]]
```

As you are a Windows user, probably you will have to change Macintosh->Windows in the path. I guess then you will have to restart Mathematica, but as I told you, i've never tried it before.