# Undo (CTRL Z as well as under edit) bug after pressing control shift

Tags: front-end, bugs, windows

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

As some of you might know, if you press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> on windows, you change your keyboard layout. For example, : becomes ±. This happens sometimes in Mathematica, and it results in a weird bug: control z no longer works, even after you change back. Sometimes I'll be writing and suddenly I see ±, so I know I have to press control shift, and I can type : again. However, if I use control z, it opens the wolfram demonstrations page  http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/, and so does undo under edit. The only way of getting rid of this is completely quitting Mathematica, which is quite a hassle, especially as I usually find out when I want to actually undo something. This means that I actually cannot undo this, which is very problematic in some cases.

Does anyone have experience with this bug?

Comment: In (my) Windows 7 Control-Shift-: does not work the way you describe.  Does this feature need to be turned on somewhere?

Comment: Hm, from what I know is that it changes the keyboard layout. It appears to be under Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options -> Languages tab -> Details. I suppose I could turn off the shortcut, but that still doesn't explain why mathematica changes its undo into opening the demonstrations page, even after switching back layouts.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed as of version 10.0.2.

See also these other questions: [(58799)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58799), [(60408)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60408/), [(72750)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72750) and [(90054)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90054).