# Why insert menu shortcuts sometime run other actions?

Tags: keyboard

I am new in Mathematica. I am wondering, why insert menu shortcuts, like `ctrl + ^`, or `ctrl + _` sometimes result in another action, e.g. "find on page", or "open a new Notebook"?

I really didn't change any settings. Mathematica 10.

Thanks

Edit: Switching the keyboard language helps, but for a short time.

Edit2: Even `ctrl +s`, `ctrl +c`, `ctrl+v` sometimes result in another action, although in other applications, like Microsoft Word, Visual Studio or Matlab, everything works well.

Edit3: I noticed this "feature" long time ago. Restarting PC/Mathematica doesn't help.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior? Otherwise, as you probably know, it is essentially impossible to track its origin down.

Comment: Are you using a non-English keyboard setting maybe?

Comment: I have 2 keyboards, but I think main is English. Actually switching between languages helps to fix this problem, but for a short time

Comment: How can I reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Even `ctrl+v` sometimes doesn't work properly. I don't have any hotkey programs running

Comment: What does $ReleaseNumber return?

Comment: `$ReleaseNumber` returns `1`

Comment: You should upgrade to 10.0.2, which should resolve your issue.

Comment: Also the same issue as [(58799)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58799)

Comment: ilian, thanks for the link. Yes, I have exactly the same issue.